# How to add ripple effect to PhysicalModel in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I was trying to create a login button, which will be animated on pressing on it. But while clicking on the button( on the PhysicalModel), a ripple effect is shown only on the Login text, not entirely on the physical model. How to add ripples to PhysicalModel or remove the ripple effect from MaterialButton ?

```
PhysicalModel(
            color: Colors.teal,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            child: MaterialButton(
                   key: _globalKey,
                   child: Text("Login"),
                   onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                             if (_state == 0) {
                                    animateButton();
                             }
                        });
                   },
                   elevation: 4.0,
                   minWidth: _width,
                   height: 20.0,
            ),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the splash color of the `MaterialButton` just change these colors to transparent.

```
  MaterialButton(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
```

If you want ripple effect for your `PhysicalModel`:

```
    PhysicalModel(
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                    child: Text("Login"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    elevation: 4.0,
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: Done. This will remove the ripple effect. What if I need a ripple effect, but for the entire widget? Any soln?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, you can simply set Your PhysicModel color to transparent, while using a Ink widget set color to what you need for your child widget:

```
PhysicalModel(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                        shadowColor: Colors.grey.withAlpha(10),
                        elevation: 16,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Ink(
                            color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                            child:
```

It's simply, and then you can have Inkwell effect as well as keep your color.

Answer (score -1):

**[Adding Material Touch Ripples](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/gestures/ripples)**

Flutter provides the [InkWell](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) Widget to achieve this effect.

Definition:

> A rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch.

[image: Inkwell Image]

Also: The InkWell widget must have a Material widget as an ancestor. The Material widget is where the ink reactions are actually painted. This matches the material design premise wherein the Material is what is actually reacting to touches by spreading ink.

> **Directions**

1. Create a Widget we want to tap
2. Wrap it in an InkWell Widget to manage tap callbacks and ripple
   animations

   ```
       InkWell(
           // When the user taps the button, show a snackbar
           onTap: () {
             Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
               content: Text('Tap'),
             ));
           },
           child: PhysicalModel(
             color: Colors.teal,
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
             child: MaterialButton /*or a FlatButton */(
               key: _globalKey,
               child: Text("Login"),
               onPressed: () {
                 setState(() {
                   if (_state == 0) {
                     animateButton();
                   }
                 });
               },
               elevation: 4.0,
               minWidth: _width,
               height: 20.0,
             ),
           )),
   ```